# Git merge deleted file conflict

Tags: git

When I run my merge command in Terminal:

```
git merge 
--allow-unrelated-histories private-repo/master 
--strategy-option=theirs 
-m "Some message for merge editor."
```

I receive this conflict error:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): 
./config.yml deleted in HEAD and modified in private-repo/master. 
Version private-repo/master of ./config.yml left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Is there a way how can I fix it automatically without doing manual job?

I tried this command `-X rename-threshold=100%` but it also did not help.
I hope you could help me. If you have any questions please ask me.

Comment: Deleting and modifying the same file is a conflict.

Comment: @matt I'm trying to merge 2 repos. The repo which I'm going to merge contains that file but the repo into which I'm going to merge does not. So the issue is, I suppose. Is there a way how can I avoid this error and just do not include that file on merge or some other solution?

Comment: Do you want to keep that `config.yml` file ? or to drop it from the final commit ?

Comment: @LeGEC to drop it

Comment: About the "automatically" part : do you want to fix the issue for this one merge ? or do you have, for some reason, to run several similar `git merge` commands ? possibly from a script ?

Comment: It's not an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way how can I fix it automatically without doing manual job?

No.

> I tried this command `-X rename-threshold=100%` but it also did not help.

This isn't a *command*.  It's a modifier for the `git merge` command, and it indeed will not help at all.  It sets the minimum level for Git to detect a rename to be a 100%-exact-match for a file, but your conflict is a modify/delete conflict, not a rename/*thing* conflict for any *thing*.

Modify/delete conflicts are what I call *high level* conflicts, and some others call *tree* conflicts.  Tree conflicts *always* require manual resolution.  (There are other kinds of high-level / tree conflicts, including add/add and rename/delete for instance, but here you had a modify/delete conflict.)

[LeGEC asked, in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67685234/git-merge-deleted-file-conflict#comment119637914_67685234), whether you wanted to keep the `config.yml`, or delete it entirely; you said that you want to delete it.  So tell Git to delete it:

> ```
> Version private-repo/master of ./config.yml left in tree.
> ```

Run either (but not both) of the following:

1. `git rm ./config.yml`: you'll get a complaint but the file will be gone.
2. `rm ./config.yml` and then `git add ./config.yml`.  This takes two commands but you'll get no complaints this time, and the file will be gone.

Resolve any additional conflicts (it looks like there are none) and then run `git merge --continue` to finish the merge.